# What is the scope of waterfall sync in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I've got a problem, that when I call a function from within the waterfall function that is doing some asynchronous job, the waterfall doesn't wait for it to end, it moves on right to the final "error handling" function of the waterfall.

I would expect the waterfall purpose is to make things synchronous and wait, so either I am not understanding the concept or I am doing something wrong.

My waterfall:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        // If there is no such file error is thrown and next iteration of the loop starts
        var prepend="processed__"
        var fileName = prepend + configFile.importFileName;
        util.log("Checking if there is any processed file on the SFTP matching one in schedule config: "+fileName);
        sftpHandler.checkIfExists(generalConfig.sftpPathToImportFiles, fileName, callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
        var oldPrepend="processed__"
        var oldName = oldPrepend+configFile.importFileName;
        var newPrepend = "being_imported__";
        var newName = newPrepend+configFile.importFileName;
        var path = generalConfig.sftpPathToImportFiles;
        var oldPath = path + oldName;
        var newPath = path + newName;
        util.log("Going to rename the file from: "+oldName+" to: "+newName);
        sftpHandler.renameFileOnSftp(oldPath, newPath, callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
        var criterion = {'SCHID':configFile.SCHID, 'Status': 'queued'};
        util.log("Reading data from DB. Criterion: "+JSON.stringify(criterion));
        MongoClient.readData(criterion, generalConfig.RecordModel, callback);
    },
    function(docs, callback) {
        // Check if there are any data in the DB for the processed csv file, if not, archive the file, else do bulk import
        if (docs){
            util.log("Data retrieved: "+JSON.stringify(docs));
            callback(null, docs);
            // No need to do anything here, bulk import will be in the next step
        }else{
            util.log("There wasn't any data in the DB for this csv file: "+ configFile.importFileName);
            var prepend = "being_imported__";
            var path = generalConfig.sftpPathToImportFiles;
            var oldName = prepend + configFile.importFileName;
            var oldPath = path + oldName;
            var newPath = path + "/archive/"+configFile.importFileName;
            // This function also moves file
            sftpHandler.renameFileOnSftp(oldPath, newPath, callback);
        }
        //MongoClient.readData(generalConfig.criterion, generalConfig.RecordModel, callback);
    },
    function(docs, callback) {
        // If docs is not undefined, there were some documents/elements in DB for this file
        if (docs){
            // Do bulk import - This function is only passing a data to the next function in Waterfall
            util.log("Going to post import definition.");
            postImportDefinition(docs, configFile.importDefinition, configFile.importType, configFile,  callback);
        }else{
            // Since there were no elements in DB for this file, continue processing next schedule config file
            i++;
            util.log("Recursively calling waterfall process due to missing elements in DB for this file. Iteration #"+i);
            waterfallMain(configFiles, i);
            return;
        }
    },
    function(docs, uri, callback) {
        util.log("Going to post the data to the: "+uri+", length - "+docs.length);
        postData(docs, uri, callback);
    },
    // Passed docs to be able to change the status in the database for these items
    function(docs, syncUri, callback) {
        getSyncResponseInIntervals(docs, syncUri, callback);
    }],

// The final callback function
function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        util.log(err);
        switch (err.location){
            case BULK_IMPORT_ERR_LOCATION:
            // Update database by setting documents status attribute to failed
                MongoClient.updateData(docs, "fail", generalConfig.RecordModel, waterfallRecursiveCallback);
                break;
            case NO_SUCH_SFTP_FILE_ERR_LOCATION:
                waterfallRecursiveCallback();
                break;
            default:
                // Update database by setting documents status to finished (at this point it shouldn't happen that docs obj is empty, as it is handled in previous functions in waterfall)
                MongoClient.updateData(docs, "success", generalConfig.RecordModel, waterfallRecursiveCallback);
        }

        function waterfallRecursiveCallback(){
            // If the loop is at it's last iteration, do the main process all over again in 1 minute
            // This happens when there are no unprocessed files for the each of the configuration files
            if (i == configFiles.length-1) {
                util.log("Last iteration of config files. Going to run mainProcess() in 1 minute.");
                setTimeout(function(){
                        mainProcess();
                        return;
                }, 60000);
                return;
            }
            // Recursively calling waterfall process again (this happens when there was no unprocessed file on the SFTP for given config - schedule config)
            i++;
            util.log("Recursively calling waterfall process. Iteration #"+i);
            //util.log(JSON.stringify(configFiles));
            waterfallMain(configFiles, i);
            return;
        }
    }
```

The problem happens on the very first function when I call `sftpHandler.checkIfExists()`.

My `checkIfExists()`:

```
SftpHandler.prototype.checkIfExists = function (path, fileName, callback) {
    var c = new sftpJsClient();
    console.log("Checking called from check if exists!!!!!!");
    c.on('ready', function () {
        console.log("C IS READY!!!!");
        c.stat(path.concat(fileName), function(err, stats) {
        if (err){
                console.log("ERROR WHILE CHECKING"+err);
                err.location = generalConfig.NO_SUCH_SFTP_FILE_ERR_LOCATION;
                callback(err);
                return;
            }else{
                console.log("Checking if file exists successfull."+JSON.stringify(stats));
                // could rather use stats.isFile() here, but it's not necessary because if file doesn't exist it throws an error
                callback(null);
                return;
            }
        });
    }).connect(this.sftpConnect);
};
```

And the output log:

```
5 Aug 09:46:50 - Running through all config files. Count: 3
5 Aug 09:46:50 - Checking if there is any processed file on the SFTP matching one in schedule config: processed__test1.csv
Checking called from check if exists!!!!!!
C IS READY!!!!
ERROR WHILE CHECKINGError: /E-drive/sftp/VismaReports/Test/QueueSystem/processed__test1.csv not found
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Error: /E-drive/sftp/VismaReports/Test/QueueSystem/processed__test1.csv not found
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Recursively calling waterfall process. Iteration #1
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Checking if there is any processed file on the SFTP matching one in schedule config: processed__test2.csv
Checking called from check if exists!!!!!!
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Waterfall process has ended, executing a mainProcess()
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Main process started.
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Running through all config files. Count: 3
5 Aug 09:46:51 - Checking if there is any processed file on the SFTP matching one in schedule config: processed__test1.csv
Checking called from check if exists!!!!!!
C IS READY!!!!
ERROR WHILE CHECKINGError: /E-drive/sftp/VismaReports/Test/QueueSystem/processed__test1.csv not found
5 Aug 09:46:52 - Error: /E-drive/sftp/VismaReports/Test/QueueSystem/processed__test1.csv not found
5 Aug 09:46:52 - Recursively calling waterfall process. Iteration #1
5 Aug 09:46:52 - Checking if there is any processed file on the SFTP matching one in schedule config: processed__test2.csv
Checking called from check if exists!!!!!!
5 Aug 09:46:52 - Waterfall process has ended, executing a mainProcess()
```

In the output you may see that log `C IS READY !!!!` is missing on every second call of the function. Which I assume is because `c.on` is asynchronous and therefore waterfall moves on without waiting on the `c.on`.

**But why does it move on if I haven't done the `callback`?**

**EDIT:**

When I comment out the `c.on` function, the waterfall is hanging and waiting for callback to be called, just as expected, but why would it move on when I uncomment it and not wait for the callback?

Answer (score 0):

As said on [official website](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall) :

> Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their
>   results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an
>   error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and
>   the main callback is immediately called with the error.

You get the error as you can see with log `ERROR WHILE CHECKING` which cause the

> the main callback is immediately called with the error

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but no you are not getting my point. I want exactly what you have just described, but check this log: `5 Aug 09:46:51 - Checking if...` after that this: `C IS READY!!!!` should be called, but wasn't. Instead the main callback waterfall function was called without any error!

Comment: It is probably never ready and app is just waiting and waiting, while next main process started and writing logs. Also be careful about standard output and error output, it usually works independently, therefore error output does not reflect the "position" of when you log it with standard output.

Comment: It's not waiting not even a second, as you may see on log timestamps. It's just jumping forward right away.

Comment: It is probably waiting all the time (thus never ends and you brake it somehow or it crashes). After `5 Aug 09:46:51 - Checking` there is no `C IS READY!!!!`. But also there is no `Recursively calling` at the end and also there is no `Going to rename`, which is in another method.

Comment: Might be the case hmm

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the second call, the one where it tries to read `processed__test2.csv`, never completes. Seems like it hangs in `checkIfExists` for that file, and the `.on()` callback for the sftp client is never called.

There seems to be also quite a lot of going on, reading two different files and two times each. However, the log says `Running through all config files. Count: 3` which is either off-by-one error or something fishy is going on.

Could you try to isolate the problem: repeat the failing scenario with only one file.